# laravel 7. Url id encryption: The payload is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, url

I must admit that i am a bit confused and stuck of how i can encrypt my url id in my project. i have browsed different methods of encryption but just don't know how to make them  fit in this project. only have one method ('index') and the query to view posts is not directly in the controller. This is what  i tried. Any other encryption will help

#### AdminController

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

 public function index(Admin $admin)
{
    $data = Crypt::decrypt($admin);
    return view('admin', compact('admin'));
}
```

#### admin blade

```
<?php
    $admin =[
        'id' =>1,
    ];
$admin= Crypt::encrypt($admin); ?>


 @foreach($admin->posts as $post)
                <div class="col-4">
                    <img src="/storage/{{$post->image}}" class="w-30" alt="">
                </div>
                 @endforeach
               
                
               
                @foreach($admin->posts as $post)
                <div class="col-4"> {{$post->about }}
                </div>
                                
                @endforeach
```

#### AdminLogincontrollerController

// The id is given to the route after the admin logs in through this controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // validate the input from the admin
    $this->validate($request, 
    ['email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    //  attempt admin to log in
    if(auth::guard('SuperAdmin')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password], $request->get('remember')))
    {
        $admin = Auth::guard('SuperAdmin')->id();

            return    redirect()->route('admin.dashboard',['admin'=>$admin]);
    }
```

#### route in web.php

```
   Route::get('/admin/{admin}', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
```